# Using ftp upload to site C# ASP.NET web form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

I opened my ftp website and there I created web form.

This is my .cs code where I get error:

```
public partial class http://Chiragdani.somee.com/Jurnali.aspx : System.Web.UI.Page
{//here I get error:"Type expected"

       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }

}
```

What should I do? 
Please help.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ":" is the error. Try "something" like this.

```
public partial class Jurnali : System.Web.UI.Page
{
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

       }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Error1 Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class.

Comment: Error3 'ASP.www_chiragdani_somee_com_jurnali_aspx.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext)': no suitable method found to override.

Comment: Error2 'ASP.www_chiragdani_somee_com_jurnali_aspx.GetTypeHashCode()': no suitable method found to override.

Comment: Error4 'ASP.www_chiragdani_somee_com_jurnali_aspx' does not implement interface member 'System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable'

Comment: Try to remove the inherits. Remove : System.Web.UI.Page